# Manual ISR not revalidating all domains on Vercel

Tags: vercel

I recently added a domain to my Next.js app on Vercel. My old URL was `foo-bar.vercel.app`. And now it is `nice.com` (examples). I notice that my `res.revalidate('/page')` now is making a call to revalidate `https://nice.com/page`. And visting my old `https://foo-bar.vercel.app/page` is showing outdated info. Why is this? Shouldn't both domains point to the exact same resource/page? Do I have to make `revalidate` also revalidate my old domain?